# Adding print statements to cython code affects output

Tags: python, windows, cython, appveyor

I have an application that's written in a combination of Python and Cython.  I recently added a new feature and tests to this application.  The tests pass on my local machine (a macbook), but when I push to appveyor (a Windows CI service) the tests fail.  This in itself is not so strange.  When I add print statements to my Cython code in an attempt to see what is happening when it runs on appveyor, the tests no longer fail.  This is frustrating because it leaves me no way to figure out what's happening when the tests fail on appveyor.  It also is just perplexing because it violates my understanding of how Python and Cython work in general.

My code is complex and there's no reasonable way for me to share an example of this phenomenon.  However, I'm looking for reasons this could happen.  How and in what situations might a print statement in Cython code have an effect on other computations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical case in my experience is where you've managed to grab a value from unallocated or unaligned storage -- in short, a memory usage error that finesses the compiler's ability to detect such abuse.  Normally, you get a garbage value; the print statement forces an evaluation or memory alignment that "fixes" the problem.

This is hard to do accidentally in most modern languages, unless you specifically "hard-cast" a value, changing a type without altering the bit value.

Comment: The problem turned out to be an uninitialized integer that needed to be initialized to zero.  On the macbook it started at zero anyway, but I guess on Windows it was just whatever random value was at the memory location.  The thing I still don't understand is why printing a particular combination of other variables seemed to fix the problem.  However, I suspect it's something close to what you're describing.

Comment: Aha!  I'm disappointed that your code allowed the uninitialized variable; I'm quite accustomed to the first reference getting a run-time error.  Yes, I expect that the added **print** just happened to bump a fistful of 0 bits into the necessary location for you.

Comment: In normal Python you do get a run-time error when you attempt to use the value of an uninitialized variable.  In Cython, you can declare a variable like in C without initializing it.  So I declared an int counter but forgot to set its initial value to zero.

Answer (score 1):

To save some time, you can try to debug deeper using blocking RDP (https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/rdp-to-build-worker/) which you can insert in different stages of Appveyor build. Just please note that Environment variables in RDP session are not the same as for build agent process so you might need to adjust RDP environment to get a repo.

--ilya.